# Image rounded corners in QML

Tags: qml, qt5, qtquick2

To my surprise, the `Image` component has no `radius` property. I tried emulating the rounded corners by putting the image in a rounded `Rectangle`, but it does not clip the corners.

```
Rectangle {
    anchors.right: rectContentBg.left
    anchors.top: rectContentBg.top
    anchors.margins: 8

    radius: 8

    width: 64
    height: 64

    Image {
        id: imgAuthor

        opacity: 1
        smooth: false

        anchors.fill: parent

        source: "qrc:/res/sample_avatar.jpg"
    }
}
```

How can I create an image with rounded corners properly?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

A built-in official solution exists as of Qt 5 thanks to the `QtGraphicalEffects` module and I'm quite surprised to find out that no one provided such a simple solution. If you are targeting Qt 6.x `QtGraphicalEffects` is unfortunately deprecated so jump to the second part of the answer which proposes a solution independent of `QtGraphicalEffects`.

### `QtGraphicalEffects` solution

Among the other effects `OpacityMask` is the type to be exploited for this purpose. The idea is to mask the source `Image` with a `Rectangle` that has a correctly set `radius`. Here goes the simplest example using [layering](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#item-layers):

```
Image {
    id: img
    property bool rounded: true
    property bool adapt: true

    layer.enabled: rounded
    layer.effect: OpacityMask {
        maskSource: Item {
            width: img.width
            height: img.height
            Rectangle {
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                width: img.adapt ? img.width : Math.min(img.width, img.height)
                height: img.adapt ? img.height : width
                radius: Math.min(width, height)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This minimum code produces a nice result for square images but
it also takes in account non-square images via the `adapt` variable. By setting the flag to `false` the produced mask will always be a circle, regardless of the image size. That is possible due to the usage of an external `Item` which fills the source and allows the real mask (the inner `Rectangle`) to be sized at please. *You can obviously get rid of the external `Item`, if you simply aim to a mask that fills the source, regardless of the its aspect ratio*.

Here is a cute cat image with a square format (**left**), a non-square format with `adapt: true` (**center**) and finally a non-square  format and `adapt: false` (**right**):

[image]

The implementation details of this solution are very similar to those of the shader-based answer in the other [nice answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31070908/2538363) (cfr. the QML source code for `OpacityMask` that can be found [here](http://ftp.fau.de/qtproject/ministro/android/qt5/objects/5.1014-x86/qml/QtGraphicalEffects/OpacityMask.qml) - `SourceProxy` simply returns a well-formed `ShaderEffectSource` to feed the effect).

### No-dep solution

If you don't want to - *or can't* - depend on the `QtGraphicalEffects` module (well, on the presence of `OpacityMask.qml` actually), you can reimplement the effect with shaders. Apart from the already provided solution another approach is to use [`step`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/step.xhtml), [`smoothstep`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/smoothstep.xhtml) and [`fwidth`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/fwidth.xhtml) functions. Here is the code:

```
import QtQuick 2.5

Image {
    id: image

    property bool rounded: true
    property bool adapt: true

    layer.enabled: rounded
    layer.effect: ShaderEffect {
        property real adjustX: image.adapt ? Math.max(width / height, 1) : 1
        property real adjustY: image.adapt ? Math.max(1 / (width / height), 1) : 1

        fragmentShader: "
        #ifdef GL_ES
            precision lowp float;
        #endif // GL_ES
        varying highp vec2 qt_TexCoord0;
        uniform highp float qt_Opacity;
        uniform lowp sampler2D source;
        uniform lowp float adjustX;
        uniform lowp float adjustY;

        void main(void) {
            lowp float x, y;
            x = (qt_TexCoord0.x - 0.5) * adjustX;
            y = (qt_TexCoord0.y - 0.5) * adjustY;
            float delta = adjustX != 1.0 ? fwidth(y) / 2.0 : fwidth(x) / 2.0;
            gl_FragColor = texture2D(source, qt_TexCoord0).rgba
                * step(x * x + y * y, 0.25)
                * smoothstep((x * x + y * y) , 0.25 + delta, 0.25)
                * qt_Opacity;
        }"
    }
}
```

[image]

Similarly to the first approach, `rounded` and `adapt` properties are added to control the visual appearance of the effect as discussed above.

Comment: Great answer, thanks! I want to point out something in your first approach that if you are using a single rectangle in an item, you don't need to declare the item and can use rectangle directly because rectangle inherits item.

Comment: Why do you wrap the `Rectangle` in an `Item`?

Comment: @Phrogz the effect fils the source and even if I set `adapt` to `true` I cannot have the result in the third picture of the first series. If you have a square picture like in the first picture, the outer `Item` is simply useless.

Comment: want to add , if you targeting mobile device you should set layer.textureSize, so you keep the full resolution

Comment: QtGraphicalEffects is discontinued in Qt6

Answer (score 9):

This code would help you

```
Rectangle {
    width: 200
    height: 200

    color: "transparent"

    //this Rectangle is needed to keep the source image's fillMode
    Rectangle {
        id: imageSource

        anchors.fill: parent
        Image {
            anchors.fill: parent
            source: "your_image_file_path"

            fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectCrop
        }
        visible: false

        layer.enabled: true
    }

    Rectangle {
        id: maskLayer
        anchors.fill: parent
        radius: parent.width / 2

        color: "red"

        border.color: "black"

        layer.enabled: true
        layer.samplerName: "maskSource"
        layer.effect: ShaderEffect {

            property var colorSource: imageSource
            fragmentShader: "
                uniform lowp sampler2D colorSource;
                uniform lowp sampler2D maskSource;
                uniform lowp float qt_Opacity;
                varying highp vec2 qt_TexCoord0;
                void main() {
                    gl_FragColor =
                        texture2D(colorSource, qt_TexCoord0)
                        * texture2D(maskSource, qt_TexCoord0).a
                        * qt_Opacity;
                }
            "
        }

    }

    // only draw border line
    Rectangle {
        anchors.fill: parent

        radius: parent.width / 2

        border.color: "black"
        border.width: 2

        color: "transparent"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

When your background is a solid color or when you're never moving the image, a fast way to make rounded corners is to overlap your `Image` with another one (or with a [`BorderImage`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qml-borderimage.html)) that only draws the corners.

When this is not an option, but you are using OpenGL, then another way is to apply a mask to the image through a pixel shader. See http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2011/05/03/qml-shadereffectitem-on-qgraphicsview/ for a plugin that works on top of Qt 4.

Finally, it's also possible to write a [`QDeclarativeImageProvider`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdeclarativeimageprovider.html) that preprocesses your image to make the corners rounded.

Answer (score 7):

While both the accepted answer and [the one from @fury](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44462145/3246449) worked equally well for me (Qt 5.9.3), they both left some aberrations in the corners when applied to raster images (didn't have those with SVG).  What worked best for me in all cases was to apply the `OpacityMask` to a surrounding item, e.g. like the rectangle in the original post.

```
Rectangle {
    id: root;
    anchors.right: rectContentBg.left
    anchors.top: rectContentBg.top
    anchors.margins: 8

    radius: 8

    width: 64
    height: 64

    // apply rounded corners mask
    layer.enabled: true
    layer.effect: OpacityMask {
        maskSource: Rectangle {
            x: root.x; y: root.y
            width: root.width
            height: root.height
            radius: root.radius
        }
    }

    Image {
        id: imgAuthor
        opacity: 1
        smooth: false
        anchors.fill: parent
        source: "qrc:/res/sample_avatar.jpg"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

If you have a unicolor background, you can draw with the border of a rounded rectangle on top.

```
Image{
    id:img
}
Rectangle { // rounded corners for img
    anchors.fill: img
    color: "transparent"
    border.color: "blue" // color of background
    border.width: 4
    radius: 4
}
```

Comment: it works so long as radius is larger than border.width

Comment: whilst this answer does work, I am left with occasional rendering artefacts meaning it doesn't look very professional on its own. Fortunately the glitches are only the vertical lines (on win7) so 2 well placed rectangles can clean it up.

Answer (score 4):

QML currently supports only rectangular clipping, but you might want to take a look at DeclarativeMaskedImage in qt-components project:

http://qt.gitorious.org/qt-components/qt-components/blobs/master/src/symbian/sdeclarativemaskedimage.h

Comment: They really should make this happen instead of fancy 3D stuff they are doing now :/

Comment: DeclarativeMaskedImage  borken link

Answer (score 4):

I know I'm a little late to the party, but I got here by googling, so thought I'd help future generations :) QtGraphicalEffects OpacityMask should do this a bit more simply (I had issues with the layer effect approach)

```
Image {
    id: imgAuthor

    width: 64
    height: 64

    source: "qrc:/res/sample_avatar.jpg"

    visible: false // this is needed or the corners of the image will be visible underneath the opacity mask
}

OpacityMask {
    anchors.fill: imgAuthor
    source: imgAuthor
    maskSource: Rectangle {
        width: imgAuthor.width
        height: imgAuthor.height
        radius: 8
        visible: false // this also needs to be invisible or it will cover up the image
    }
}
```

Comment: Not suitable for Qt6 , QtGraphicalEffects  module is discontinued

Answer (score 1):

If you have a unicolor background, you can draw with the border of a rounded rectangle on top.

```js
Item {
    property int radius: 0
    property color bgColor: "#000000"
    property int drawRadius: radius > 0 ? radius : width/2

    Image {
        anchors.fill: parent
        sourceSize: Qt.size(width, height)
        asynchronous: true
    }

    Canvas {
        anchors.fill: parent
        antialiasing: true
        onPaint: {
            var ctx = getContext("2d")
            ctx.fillStyle = bgColor
            ctx.beginPath()
            ctx.rect(0, 0, width, height)
            ctx.fill()

            ctx.beginPath()
            ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-out'
            ctx.roundedRect(0, 0, width, height, drawRadius, drawRadius)
            ctx.fill()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: one of the correct answers for Qt6 where QtGraphicalEffects module is only a legacy