# Image with rounded corners and PreserveAspectFit in Qt

Tags: qt, qml

I'm aware of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6090740/image-rounded-corners-in-qml/31070908#31070908), but it doesn't work for:

```
fillMode: PreserveAspectFit
```

Such change results in solid color strips on the sides of the picture. Is there any way to make work without them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `paintedWidth` and `paintedHeight` properties of `Image` (see [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-image.html#paintedHeight-prop)).

I find using `OpacityMask` from QtGraphicalEffects easier than the shader from the mentioned answer (not sure about performance).

```
import QtQuick 2.11
import QtQuick.Window 2.11
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.0

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Image {
        id: img
        anchors.fill: parent
        source: "your_non_fitting_image.png"

        fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
        visible: false
    }

    Item {
        id: mask
        anchors.fill: img
        visible: false

        Rectangle {
            color: "white"
            radius: 20
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            width: img.paintedWidth
            height: img.paintedHeight
        }
    }

    OpacityMask {
        anchors.fill: img
        source: img
        maskSource: mask
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that you can use Item instead of a transparent Rectangle

Comment: `QtGraphicalEffects` is deprecated at Qt 6. Is there any other solution apart from that?

Comment: Probably the shader option from the mentioned answer with some extra math to fix the aspect ratio problem