# Module not found even after installing it in Qt QML 6.2.4

Tags: python-3.x, qt, qml, pyside6

I am making a Python application in QML with following env:

1. OS: Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
2. IDE: Qt Creator 9.0.2
3. Qt 6.2.4
4. Python 3.10.6

To further check I also made a qmake query according to Qt Forums and the output was:

```
QT_SYSROOT:
QT_INSTALL_PREFIX:/media/raghav/Apps/Qt/6.2.4/gcc_64
QT_INSTALL_ARCHDATA:/media/raghav/Apps/Qt/6.2.4/gcc_64
QT_INSTALL_DATA:/media/raghav/Apps/Qt/6.2.4/gcc_64
QT_INSTALL_DOCS:/media/raghav/Apps/Qt/Docs/Qt-6.2.4
QT_INSTALL_HEADERS:/media/raghav/Apps/Qt/6.2.4/gcc_64/include
QT_INSTALL_LIBS:/media/raghav/Apps/Qt/6.2.4/gcc_64/lib
QT_INSTALL_LIBEXECS:/media/raghav/Apps/Qt/6.2.4/gcc_64/libexec
QT_INSTALL_BINS:/media/raghav/Apps/Qt/6.2.4/gcc_64/bin
QT_INSTALL_TESTS:/media/raghav/Apps/Qt/6.2.4/gcc_64/tests
QT_INSTALL_PLUGINS:/media/raghav/Apps/Qt/6.2.4/gcc_64/plugins
QT_INSTALL_QML:/media/raghav/Apps/Qt/6.2.4/gcc_64/qml
QT_INSTALL_TRANSLATIONS:/media/raghav/Apps/Qt/6.2.4/gcc_64/translations
QT_INSTALL_CONFIGURATION:
QT_INSTALL_EXAMPLES:/media/raghav/Apps/Qt/Examples/Qt-6.2.4
QT_INSTALL_DEMOS:/media/raghav/Apps/Qt/Examples/Qt-6.2.4
QT_HOST_PREFIX:/media/raghav/Apps/Qt/6.2.4/gcc_64
QT_HOST_DATA:/media/raghav/Apps/Qt/6.2.4/gcc_64
QT_HOST_BINS:/media/raghav/Apps/Qt/6.2.4/gcc_64/bin
QT_HOST_LIBEXECS:/media/raghav/Apps/Qt/6.2.4/gcc_64/libexec
QT_HOST_LIBS:/media/raghav/Apps/Qt/6.2.4/gcc_64/lib
QMAKE_SPEC:linux-g++
QMAKE_XSPEC:linux-g++
QMAKE_VERSION:3.1
QT_VERSION:6.2.4
```

And below is my QML code:

```
import "../../widgets"
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Layouts 6.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtWebView 1.1

Item{
    id: settings_app
    width: 1024 ;height: 600

    /*
    Image {
        id: settings_bg
        anchors.fill: parent
        source: "../../wallpapers/sunset flowers.png"
        fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectCrop
    }

*/
    Component.onCompleted: {
        settingsApp.showName()
    }

    RowLayout {
        id: settings_layout
        anchors.fill: parent
        spacing: 0

        Rectangle {
            id: side_menu
            width: 200
            height: 200
            color: "#262626"
            Layout.maximumWidth: 300
            Layout.minimumWidth: 300
            Layout.fillHeight: true

            ColumnLayout {
                id: side_menu_layout
                anchors.fill: parent
                spacing: 0

                ColumnLayout {
                    id: side_menu_layout_up
                    height: 100
                    Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignLeft | Qt.AlignTop
                    spacing: 0

                    Layout.maximumHeight: 200
                    Layout.minimumHeight: 200
                    Layout.fillWidth: true

                    WebView{
                        id: userImg
                        url: ('qrc:/files/widgets/Circular Image/CircularImage.html')
                        Layout.fillHeight: true
                        Layout.fillWidth: true
                    }

                }

                ColumnLayout {
                    id: side_menu_layout_down
                    width: 100
                    height: 100
                    spacing: -20
                    Layout.topMargin: 30
                    Layout.maximumHeight: 370
                    Layout.minimumHeight: 370
                    Layout.fillHeight: true
                    Layout.fillWidth: true

                    MenuOption {
                        id: option_account
                        Layout.fillWidth: true
                        Layout.leftMargin: 20
                        btnText: "Account"
                        btnIcon: "qrc:/Icons/icons/account.png"
                        Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignLeft | Qt.AlignTop
                        btnColor: "transparent"
                        btnIconHeight: 32
                        btnIconWidth: 32

                        MouseArea{
                            anchors.fill: option_account
                            onClicked: {
                                option_account.btnColor = "#1f2021"
                                settings_loader.source = "./AccountPage.qml"
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    MenuOption {
                        id: option_system
                        Layout.leftMargin: 20
                        Layout.fillWidth: true
                        btnText: "Notifications"
                        btnIcon: "qrc:/Icons/icons/monitor.png"
                        Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignLeft | Qt.AlignTop
                        btnColor: "transparent"
                        btnIconHeight: 32
                        btnIconWidth: 32

                        MouseArea{
                            anchors.fill: option_system
                            onClicked: {
                                option_system.btnColor = "#1f2021"
                                settings_loader.source = "./AccountPage.qml"
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    MenuOption {
                        id: option_devices
                        Layout.leftMargin: 20
                        Layout.fillWidth: true
                        btnText: "Devices"
                        btnIcon: "qrc:/Icons/icons/cdevices.png"
                        Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignLeft | Qt.AlignTop
                        btnColor: "transparent"
                        btnIconHeight: 32
                        btnIconWidth: 32

                        MouseArea{
                            anchors.fill: option_devices
                            onClicked: {
                                option_devices.btnColor = "#1f2021"
                                settings_loader.source = "./AccountPage.qml"
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    MenuOption {
                        id: option_security
                        Layout.leftMargin: 20
                        Layout.fillWidth: true
                        btnText: "Security"
                        btnIcon: "qrc:/Icons/icons/protect.png"
                        Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignLeft | Qt.AlignTop
                        btnColor: "transparent"
                        btnIconHeight: 32
                        btnIconWidth: 32

                        MouseArea{
                            anchors.fill: option_security
                            onClicked: {
                                option_security.btnColor = "#1f2021"
                                settings_loader.source = "./AccountPage.qml"
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    MenuOption {
                        id: option_help
                        Layout.leftMargin: 20
                        Layout.fillWidth: true
                        btnText: "Help"
                        btnIcon: "qrc:/Icons/icons/info.png"
                        Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignLeft | Qt.AlignTop
                        btnColor: "transparent"
                        btnIconHeight: 32
                        btnIconWidth: 32

                        MouseArea{
                            anchors.fill: option_help
                            onClicked: {
                                option_account.btnColor = "#1f2021"
                                settings_loader.source = "./AccountPage.qml"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        ColumnLayout {
            id: main_container_layout
            width: 100
            height: 100
            Layout.maximumHeight: 600
            Layout.minimumHeight: 600
            Layout.fillHeight: true

            Layout.maximumWidth: 774
            Layout.minimumWidth: 774
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            spacing: 0

            Loader {
                id: settings_loader
                width: 200
                height: 200
                Layout.fillHeight: true
                Layout.fillWidth: true
            }
        }
    }

    Connections{
        target: settingsApp

        function onChangeDisplayName(stringText){
            displayName.text = stringText
        }
    }


}
```

The main use of WebView in this application is to display an html page which contains a circular image as I am unable to make it in QML. Well, if their is any solution to go with QML itself please suggest. I tried many solution from the Qt Forum but they didn't work.

Comment: Which module exactly wasn't found? Could you share the complete error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a circular image by using [Qt5Compat.GraphicalEffects](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtgraphicaleffects5-index.html) `OpacityMask`. The `source` is the image and the `mask` is a `Rectangle` with a `radius` that makes it a circle. Have a look at the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qt5compat-graphicaleffects-opacitymask.html).

```
Item {
    width: 400
    height: 400

    Image {
        id: image
        source: "https://picsum.photos/id/63/400/400"
        visible: false
    }

    Rectangle {
        id: mask
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height
        radius: Math.min(parent.width, parent.height) / 2
        visible: false
    }

    OpacityMask {
        anchors.fill: image
        source: image
        maskSource: mask
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Also have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6090740/image-rounded-corners-in-qml).

Comment: Thanks it worked perfectly I have trying it for 2 days. Thank you very much